# Regex to strip img and iframe tags

Tags: javascript

```
.replace(/<img[^>]+>/g, '')
```

this regex strip img tags only how can we modify this so that it strips iframe tags also along with img tags

The result regex must strip img and iframe tags only strictly. It must not strip anchor link p span blockquote etc

Comment: Using regex to parse HTML (including stripping HTML tags) is the wrong tool for the job. As this is almost definitely an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), please describe what your actual problem is so that we can help you solve it.

Answer (score 2):

There are instances that RegEx can be used to strip tags from strings such as `responseText` of `XMLHttpRequest`

For such instances you can try

```
.replace(/<img[^>]+>(<\/img>)?|<iframe.+?<\/iframe>/g, '')
```

Explanation:

```
<img[^>]+> // anythign between the <img ... >
(<\/img>)? // in case it is old style HTML
<iframe.+?<\/iframe> // anything between <iframe....</iframe> non-greedy
```

If the target is a live DOM, then use DOM to remove elements ie [Node.removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild)

Good luck
:)